# C++ SFML Sprite movement not working as intended

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using SFML with C++ to try and move a sprite with a certain texture applied, but it isn't moving as I want it to.

I'm new to SFML, I read the tutorials about movement on the sfml website, and I watched a number of tutorials on Youtube about this. The stuff I saw is either very basic, or complicated enough at the moment (mostly game development stuff)

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include<iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "test!");

        Texture t;
        t.loadFromFile("/*texture directory*/");

        Sprite s(t);
        s.setScale(Vector2f(0.25f, 0.25f));

        float temp = 0;

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear(Color::White);
            window.draw(s);
            window.display();

            s.move(Vector2f(temp, temp));


            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    temp = 10;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    temp = 20;
                }
                else {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    temp = -10;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm expecting the sprite to move to (10,10), then after a second, (20,20), then after a second, move back to (10,10).
Instead, the sprite is moving only (-10,-10) every three seconds, so it's only taking the value of temp at the end of the loop.
Same thing goes for setPosition as well.

There's something very basic at work here, but researching lead me to even more questions than answers, and that's why I've come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost `while` loop manages drawing. You have put another `for` loop inside it. The inner loop has to **finish** before the outer can continue in its iteration, i.e. drawing another frame. The execution does not happen asynchronously, therefore your `for` loop with `std::this_thread::sleep_for` calls blocks the render loop for 3 seconds total. It makes it changes to `temp`, which is unconditionally `-10` at the end.

What you want to do instead, is create **state** that persists through the render loop and make a little state machine. This state will be your `i`. Declare and initialize it near `temp` (well, you could use `temp` as well in your `if` statements) and remove the `for` loop. Do not forget to set `i` back to `0` when you're setting `temp` to `-10`, if you wish to continue the animation.

Another, possible but inferior approach is to:

1. put the rendering (and possibly event handling) code into a function;
2. call this function each time you'd wish to refresh the graphics, i.e. after each time you set `temp`, but remember to update `s` beforehand.

Lastly, I believe `sf::Sprite` has member functions for accessing the state, not only modifications, so you should be able to work just with `s`, not needing `temp`. Keep it simple and think in terms of control flow.

Comment: Please bare with me for a moment, I think I'm reaching the point. I tried to follow your instructions, here's what I ended up with: https://www.codepile.net/pile/8nzG6BdY  I can see the sprite moving by increments of (20,20), which is correct, but I'm not seeing the first two movements.

Comment: @hulululu That code suffers from the same problem as the original one. Incrementing `state` when it's `0` makes it match the second condition immediately afterwards, etc. Because of that, there should rather be a single point (after all `if`s) for the modification of state (`state = state == 2 ? 0 : state + 1;`). However, if you plan to add more animations or logic with a higher refresh rate than just 1/3Hz, you should base your animations on time, rather than controlling it (as seen in the other answer).

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel a bit stupid reading what I did last night. I used your second, inferior approach for now, what matters is that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid use of sleep on the rendering thread.

Instead, you are going to measure the time passed and move in proportion of that:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include<iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "test!");

        Texture t;
        t.loadFromFile("/*texture directory*/");

        Sprite s(t);
        s.setScale(Vector2f(0.25f, 0.25f));

        float speed = 10.0;
        sf::Clock clock;

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;

            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
            s.move(Vector2f(speed*time, speed*time));
            clock.restart();

            window.clear(Color::White);
            window.draw(s);
            window.display();


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This code allows your sprite to move to a fixed speed. You could change the speed using an additional sf::clock